# TCPListener File Transfer

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a little complication i encounter.

I may not be expert in TCP Connections but i hope someone here would help me.

This is my Client Code:

```
    void Connect(String server, String message)
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 port = 8968;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
            Byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(curSelectedFile);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


            Byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(curSelectedFile);
            Byte[] msgData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SendFile");
            Byte[] sendData = new byte[fileData.Length + msgData.Length];

            // Copy data to send package.
            msgData.CopyTo(sendData, 0);
            fileData.CopyTo(sendData, 4);

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response. 

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[256];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

This is my server one:

```
            // Listen loop.
            while(true)
            {
                using (TcpClient tcpClient = myListener.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Server] Acceptam client.");
                    using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                    {
                        // Buffer for reading data
                        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
                        var data = new List<byte>();

                        int length;

                        while ((length = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            var copy = new byte[length];
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, copy, 0, length);
                            data.AddRange(copy);
                        }

                        // Incercam sa vedem ce doreste clientul.
                        string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data[0], 0, length);
                        if(msg.StartsWith("SendFile"))
                        {
                            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\test.mp3", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                                networkStream.Position = 4;
                                binaryFormatter.Serialize(networkStream, data.ToArray());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

What i'm trying to do here:
- I want the client to send a Message.. like "SaveFile" & after this string to be the filedata.
- The server should read the client message, and to process stuff according to the Client sentstring, before doing something with the file.

I believe that i don't know how to do it.

May i have an example on how to send/receive and read certain strings from the beggining of the file? How i can put them in the byte array and how to read it... It's quite overwhelming..

PS: The current Server Code is reading the data and CAN write as i coded it, without losing any packages. But also he's writing the aditional packets i sent before i converted the bytes of the file.

Answer (score 0):

`networkStream.Position = 4;` isn't legal, because `NetworkStream` is not seekable.

I would discourage you from mixing text and binary data, just because of the complication it makes in the application protocol. But if you really want to do that, you should use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`, because it can write strings to a stream which can then be read later without consuming the bytes after the string.

Then you can do something like this...

In the client:

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(networkStream);

writer.Write("SendFile");
writer.Write(fileData.Length);
writer.Write(fileData);
```

In the server:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);

switch (reader.ReadString())
{
    case "SendFile":
    {
        int length = reader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] fileData = reader.ReadBytes(length);
        // ... then do whatever with fileData, like write to a file
        break;
    }
}
```

The `BinaryWriter/Reader` implementation of the length-counted string is non-standard, so if you wanted to interact with any other non-.NET code using this technique, it would be more complicated because you have to replicate/reimplement the non-standard length-counting logic yourself.

IMHO a better approach is to encode commands as fixed-length data, e.g. an 8-, 16-, or 32-bit value, which is just some integer that specifies the command. Then you can list your commands in the code as an `enum` type, casting to/from the network stream for the I/O. This would be more portable, easier to implement on non-.NET platforms.

Comment: Thanks for advice, i'll avoid as much as possible to transfer strings & binary in the same array.